# C++ OpenGL Textured Cube Missing Triangles

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures, glfw

On my journey towards being competent at OpenGL, I was trying to make a textured cube when I came upon this problem:
[image]

Only part of my cube is being rendered. There should be 12 triangles but only 3 of them are being rendered. I've looked at many tutorials, but I can't seem to find the problem/main difference between our code. Here's mine:

```
...

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (!setupGLFW()) return 1;
    setupApple();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, "Textured Cube", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        log_msg(LOG_ERROR, "Could not open a GLFW3 window!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!setupGLEW()) return 1;

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    static const int vertices = 12 * 3;
    static const GLfloat points[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         1.0, -1.0,  1.0
    };


    static const GLfloat textureCoords[] = {
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
        0, 0,
        1, 0,
        0, 1,
        0, 1,
        1, 0,
        1, 1,
    };

    GLuint pointBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &pointBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 3, points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint textureBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &textureBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 2, textureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pointBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GLuint program = getProgramFromFiles("text_cube.vs.glsl", "text_cube.fs.glsl");
    glm::mat4 MVP = calculateMVP();
    GLuint texture = loadBMP("uvtemplate.bmp");

    if (!program) {
        log_msg(LOG_ERROR, "There was a problem opening shader.\n");

        // clean up
        return 1;
    }

    if (!texture) {
        log_msg(LOG_ERROR, "There was a problem opening shader.\n");

        // clean up
        return 1;
    }

    glUseProgram(program);

    GLuint MVPID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
    GLuint textureID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "cube_texture");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(textureID, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) && glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    // clean up
    return 0;
}
```

Just so you know, the error is not with `setupGLFW()`, `setupApple()`, `setupGLEW()`, `getProgramFromFiles()`, `calculateMVP()`, `loadBMP()`, or my vertex and fragment shaders, which are in different files. This compiles fine because I include `GLFW` and `GLEW` from `myglutils.h` This is `uvtemplate.bmp`, its a 512x512 image:
[image]

If you guys could help me, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the call to `glBufferData()`. You set the size in floats but you have to specify it in bytes using `sizeof(GLfloat)`. That's why OpenGL isn't receiving all of your data.

```
void glBufferData
    (
    GLenum target,
    GLsizeiptr size,
    const GLvoid* data,
    GLenum usage
    );
```

So you need to replace:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 3, points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 2, textureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

with:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), textureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I made that mistake! I've done that for all of my other programs in OpenGL, I don't know why my brain slipped there. Thanks so much!